# Is the linear operator $T_2^{-1}T_1 :U_1 \to U_2$ bounded if $T_1\in L(U_1,H)\ \ T_2 \in L(U_2,H)$ $\mathrm{ker}\ T_2=\{0\} $?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $U_1, U_2, H$ are Hilbert spaces. $T_1\in L(U_1,H)\ \ T_2 \in L(U_2,H)$, $\mathrm{ker}\ T_2=\{0\} $, and the image of  $\ T_1,T_2$ are the same, i.e. $\mathrm{Im}\ T_1=\mathrm{Im}\ T_2$,

My question is

> Is the linear operator  $T_2^{-1}T_1 :U_1 \to U_2$ bounded?

Comment: What is $L(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Comment: @MattN. I imagine it's the space of linear operators from $\cdot$ to $\cdot$.

Comment: Yeah, it is the space of linear operators from $\cdot$ to $\cdot$

Comment: Linear but not necessarily continuous?

Comment: Sorry, it is the space of linear and continuous operators from $\cdot$ to $\cdot$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Thanks to the closed graph theorem, we only need to prove that if  $x_n\to x$ in $U_1$ and $T_2^{-1}T_1 x_n\to y$ in $U_2$, then $y =T_2^{-1}T_1 x$.

1. From $x_n\to x$ we get $T_1x_n\to T_1x$, applying $T_1$ to both sides.
2. From $T_2^{-1}T_1 x_n\to y$ we get $T_1 x_n\to T_2y$, applying $T_2$ to both sides.
3. Hence $T_1x = T_2y$, which means $y =T_2^{-1}T_1 x$.

Comment: Nicely done. I got hung up on trying to find a counterexample. It seemed obvious that it should be enough to pick your favourite $T_1$ and any $T_2$ (with same image) such that $T_2^{-1}$ is discontinuous. And I'm still puzzled that that's not the case.